# Create JSON in jquery

Tags: arrays, json

I want to create a JSON code in each loop, to read my input data like below, but I don't know how to achieve that.

```
{
"element1": {
    "type": "text",
    "id": "1"
  },
  "element2": {
    "type": "text",
    "id": "1"
  },
  "element3": {
    "type": "text",
    "id": "1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!,  please specify what you need exactly.there is no something called josn code json is variable type . and what is your input data ?
Do you have HTML code or JavaScript code to post, this will help us answering your question

Comment: yes i have.my HTML code is a Form Builder and i need convert Form to Json for use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correct, you should parse Json from string in cycle.

```
var jsonStringsArray = [];

jsonStringsArray.push("{\"element1\":{\"type\":\"text\",\"id\":\"1\"}}");
jsonStringsArray.push("{\"element2\":{\"type\":\"text\",\"id\":\"1\"}}");
jsonStringsArray.push("{\"element3\":{\"type\":\"text\",\"id\":\"1\"}}");

for(var i = 0; i < jsonStringsArray.length; i++) {
  console.log(JSON.parse(jsonStringsArray[i]));
}
```

Comment: jsonStringsArray.push("{\"element1\":{\"type\":\"text\",\"id\":\"1\"}}"); 

it's true but i have '2' loop and i take "element1" from Foreign loop and take "type\":\"text\",\"id\":\"1\" from Internal loop :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop on your forms inputs then extract the attributes of id and type then add them to an object like this :

```js
var inputs= document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var obj={};
for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
  obj['element'+i]={
    'id':inputs[i].getAttribute("id"),
    'type':inputs[i].getAttribute("type")
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type='text' id='input_1'/>
  <input type='tel' id='input_2'/>
  <input type='password 'id='input_3'/>
</form>
```

If you logged var obj to you console now you should see

[image]